# ScrapeFrequencyInSecs is not working in metrics-collector module

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-metrics-advisor

I have deployed metrics-collector module with a ScrapeFrequencyInSecs value of 60. so it should scrape data every minutes, but when I check data in insightsmetrics, I am still getting data every 5 minutes or so

I am using

> mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.0

Version 1.

Comment: Can you include what version of the module you are using, and the part of your deployment manifest where you set the settings?

Comment: I am using mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.0

Comment: I am setting it in the environment variables directly when deploying it through the portal. I have used type number and value 60

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer

Answer (score 1):

The `mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.0` module has `ScrapeFrequencyInSecs` **Default value: 300**.

**Note:** After updating the configuration parameter, environment variables need a **restart** of the module.

You can refer to **MS Q&A**: [can we set the interval for sending metrics using Metrics collector module to log analysis workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491984/can-we-set-the-interval-for-sending-metrics-using.html)